# How does bash knows to read autocomple from /usr/lib/git-core/

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I installed `git-flow`, which copied some bash scripts to `/usr/lib/git-core/` which are now available in bash complete. 
I know that bash reads the following directories looking for autocomplete scripts:

- `/etc/bash_completion.d/`
- `/usr/share/bash-completion/`

What makes bash aware to those new scripts? 
I installed git-flow from the debian repositories, and I am trying to understand what makes this package ticks.

I did not succeed in finding where bash determines it needs to read this directory. Looking through `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` did not help either.

#### update

Looking around, it seems that /usr/git-core/git and /usr/bin/git are the same binary file:

```
~ $ file /usr/bin/git
/usr/bin/git: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=4f634dadca99fb29ed72568d5604df087d6e6502, stripped
~ $ file /usr/lib/git-core/git
/usr/lib/git-core/git: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=4f634dadca99fb29ed72568d5604df087d6e6502, stripped
```

Comment: What is available to the completion? The sub-command names? Does `git` return them if you ask (`git help -a`)?

Comment: all git flow commands are working fine. I am just trying to understand what the debian package doing.

Comment: And I'm trying to answer that. The git completion script I have here gets the available commands by asking git (with that command). So if your new commands show up there that answers your question. Do you see them in the output of `$__git_all_commands`?

Comment: Yes, I see git flow when I issue `git help -a`.

Comment: Look for `__git_commands` in your git bash completion script (and assuming it hasn't changed too much since the version I have) you should see it calling `git help -a` to get the available commands.

Comment: I see git flow in my commands. It does not help me understand why `/usr/lib/git-core` is searched.

Comment: It isn't searched by the bash completion (which was your question). It *is* searched by git (which answers the question of how bash sees them).

Answer (score 1):

OK, given the hint from Etan, it seems, that what seems to be a bash completion is actually a git completion. As far why `/usr/lib/git-core` is search, strace shows that it's hard coded when configuring and building the package:

```
execve("/usr/bin/git", ["git", "help", "-a"], [/* 73 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xab4000
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/git-core", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 169 entries */, 32768)   = 6192
stat("/usr/lib/git-core/git-fetch-pack", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1577256, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/git-core/git-web--browse", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=4398, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/git-core/git-upload-archive", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1577256, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-store", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=765192, ...}) = 0
...
```

When compiling the package from source with `configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin/git` the strace log is:

```
execve("/usr/local/git/bin/git", ["/usr/local/git/bin/git", "help", "-a"], [/* 73 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2395000
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 159 entries */, 32768)   = 5792
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-fetch-pack", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=8448439, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-web--browse", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=4398, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-upload-archive", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=8448439, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-credential-store", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=4146627, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-p4", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=122122, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-merge-tree", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=8448439, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=8377, ...}) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The need to read `/etc/bash_completion.d` is built into bash which sources all scripts contained within this directory making any defined functionality available.

Each time you start a new terminal, this directory is re-read as part of the bash warmup procedure making all defined completions available to the shell.

Different vendors may have different directories read alongside `/etc/bash_completion.d` including `/usr/share/bash-completion` but this one is the minimum defined.

If you want to define your own completions, have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html.

Comment: Not an answer to the question of why the `/usr/lib/git-core` directory is searched.